# Widget Area disappeared under Appearance -> Widget Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

If I go to Widgets (via Appearance), I see the available widgets on the left and on the right I see nothing. A while ago everything was normal. Also the website still looks normal. But I can’t change anything anymore! Can somebody help me please?

[image]

Wordpress Ver: WordPress 4.7.4

Comment: what you have done so far , before it was working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of reason behind this problem. Might be the issue is your theme or plugin interference.

Do the following step:

1) first of all take your database backup.

2) I think you need to check your current WordPress and all plugins version which you have installed. If you found any old version then please update all these things.

3) Change your theme to another WordPress default version such as TwentySixteen and see if the widget areas come back.

4) Finally, if nothing works then try to disable all plugins and check any plugins conflict with your version?

Hope this guide will help you.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, facebook widget plugin was causing trouble, removed it. working perfect now. Thanks